# XPages ClientSide Validation in for Loop

Tags: xpages

I have 50 radiobuttonGroup in XPages. Field names are sequential like 
Field_1, Field_2, Field_3 ... up to 50.

I would like to validate all this fields in one for loop. Please find what i have tried so far but i could not solve syntax. is it possible or I am running in circles.

```
<xp:button id="btnSave"
                        styleClass="btn btn-icon btn-primary">
                        <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                            submit="false">

                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[for (var c=1; c<50; c++)
{
    var fID = "\#{id:Question_"+ c +"}";
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(fID);
    alert(elements);
    var syc = 0;
    for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++) 
    {
        if (elements[i].checked == false)
        {
            syc += 1;
        } 

    }
    if (elements.length==syc)
    {
        alert("Please select a value for question " + c);
        return false;
    }
}
]]></xp:this.script>
                        </xp:eventHandler>

 </xp:button>



      <xp:radioGroup id="Question_1" value="#{document1.Question_1}">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="One" itemValue="One"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Two" itemValue="Two"></xp:selectItem>
        </xp:radioGroup>
```

Comment: Can you provide details of where it fails?

Comment: Nothing happens when i click the button which means There is at least one error in code. I think i could not get correct syntax of ID. I am not sure i can give more details.

Answer (score 2):

Change the approach and give the input fields a common class. Then you get the collection of all fields to validate and loop through them.

You will need to check the name (radio buttons with the same name but different Id form a group) to get the grouping right. 
I would loop through them and create an object with the names as property names that are set to true if the radio button is checked and created if not checked but missing. 
At the end you have one js object with all Boolean properties. If one is false validation went wrong and you get the elements by name and add the class aria-invalid for the error

Comment: How can i give the input fields a common class. I am sorry. I do not know how to start. 
You mean that I need to create a function( ID) which gets ID as parameter? am right?

Comment: styleClass property. Translates to class= attribute

Comment: as far as I Understant I really do not know what to do :( Thank you

Comment: You use the class attribute to identify the elements. Think HTML here - it isn’t XPages specific. Typically classes are used to match to CSS, but they can be used for selection in JavaScript too. That’s what you would do here. Style in XPages here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/user/wpd_styles_apply_to_page.html Class selector here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

Comment: Thank you.. I wil try I hope I can do it :)